# Using Python, how to print output string as -> aaa3bb2c1ddddd5 when Input string is aaabbcddddd

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, arraylist

Using Python, how to print output string as  -> **aaa3bb2c1ddddd5** when Input string is **aaabbcddddd**
I want to concatenate actual character value and number of times a character is repeated in a string

```
def mycode(myString):
    lenstr = len(myString)
    print('length of string is '+str(lenstr));
    for ele in myString:
        count=0
        for character in myString:
            if character == ele:
                count = count+1
        totalstr = ele+str(count)
        
    return totalstr
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate question about *compress* a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is always sorted and grouped together like that, then you can use a `collections.Counter` to do it.

```
from collections import Counter
inp = "aaabbcddddd"
counter = Counter(inp)
out = "".join(k * v + str(v) for k,v in counter.items())
```

Or in one line:

```
print(''.join(k * v + str(v) for k,v in Counter(inp).items()))
```

Output:

```
aaa3bb2c1ddddd5
```

Or you can do it manually:

```
inp = "aaabbcddddd"
last = inp[0]
out = inp[0]
count = 1
for i in inp[1:]:
    if i == last:
        count += 1
    else:
        out += str(count)
        count = 1
        last = i
    out += i
out += str(count)
print(out)
```

Comment: Does counter mention in the docs that it preserves insertion order? Also consider a possible case like `aaabbbaaa` -> `aaa3bbb3aaa3`

Comment: @flakes  That is why I made the comment saying that if everything was sorted and grouped together.

Comment: @Alexander - do you have solution if string is not in order and unsorted/ungrouped     eg:   aaabbcddaadddcccc

Comment: Can save these two ```brackets``` like this ```''.join(k*v + str(v) for k, v in counter.items())```

Comment: @AbdQTP  my second example should do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution using a regex replacement with callback:

```py
inp = "aaabbcddddd"
output = re.sub(r'((\w)\2*)', lambda m: m.group(1) + str(len(m.group(1))), inp)
print(output)  # aaa3bb2c1ddddd5
```

Comment: Concise but slow

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner:

```
import itertools

test = 'aaabbcddddd'
out = ''.join(f"{(g := ''.join(ig))}{len(g)}" for _, ig in itertools.groupby(test))
assert out == 'aaa3bb2c1ddddd5'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like..

**Code:**

**Time Complexity: O(n)**

```
input_string="aaabbcddddd"
res=""
count=1

for i in range(1, len(input_string)):
    if input_string[i] == input_string[i-1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        res+=input_string[i-1]*count + str(count)
        count = 1

res+=input_string[-1]*count + str(count)
print(res) #aaa3bb2c1ddddd5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def char_counter_string(string):
    prev_char = None
    char_counter = 0
    output = ''
    for char_index in range(len(string)+1):
        if char_index == len(string):
            output += str(char_counter)
            break
        if string[char_index] != prev_char and prev_char is not None:
            output += str(char_counter)
            char_counter = 0
        output += string[char_index]
        char_counter += 1
        prev_char = string[char_index]
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(char_counter_string('aaabbcddddd'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, ...

Full disclosure: ... as long as the run of characters is 10 or less, it will work. I.e., if there are 11 of anything in row, this won't work (the count will be wrong).

It's just a function wrapping a `reduce`.

```python
from functools import reduce

def char_rep_count(in_string):
    return reduce(
             lambda acc, inp:
               (acc[:-1]+inp+str(int(acc[-1])+1))
                 if (inp==acc[-2])
                 else (acc+inp+"1"),
             in_string[1:],
             in_string[0]+"1"
           )
```

And here's some sample output:

```python
print(char_rep_count("aaabbcdddd"))
aaa3bb2c1dddd4
```

Comment: Clever but slow

Comment: @Pingu ... my preferred epitaph.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this fulfils the brief and is also very fast:

```
s = 'aaabbcddddd'

def mycode(myString):
    if myString:
        count = 1
        rs = [prev := myString[0]]
        for c in myString[1:]:
            if c != prev:
                rs.append(f'{count}')
                count = 1
            else:
                count += 1
            rs.append(prev := c)
        rs.append(f'{count}')
        return ''.join(rs)
    return myString
```